# Creating Test suites in Spring IDE for the Spock Test specs

Tags: groovy, junit, spock, geb

I have hundreds of test specifications written in Spock. All of these are functional tests and can be run independently. But I have come across a situation where I need to run a specific test before running some other test.

This was very easy to achieve using Junit Test Suite and it was very straight forward in Eclipse. But since all my tests are groovy tests there is no easy way to create a Test Suite in Spring IDE for the spock tests (written in Groovy).

Can someone please share some ideas as to how we can create a Test suite and run some specific tests and also define the order of tests.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think that it won't allow you to specify the order of the tests, you could use Spock's Runner configuration or @IgnoreIf/@Require built-in extensions. Have a look at [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636421/executing-specific-geb-tests-according-to-environement/18654062#18654062) to a similar question. It's probably also worth having a look at [RunnerConfiguration javadoc](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/config/RunnerConfiguration.java) as it shows that you can include classes directly instead of using annotations.

Comment: Thanks erdi. But that is a bit of a complicated solution. Is it better to have a driver script and drive the test execution from there (something like having a Hybrid framework).

Answer (score 1):

Spock specifications are valid JUnit tests (or suites) as well. That's why they are recognized by tools such as STS. You should be able to add it to the test suites as well as other JUnit test.

On the other hand it doesn't sound as a good practise if your tests depend on execution order. 
If certain tasks needs to be performed before the test execution, it should be placed in `setup()` method. If that logic is common to more than one test, consider extracting it to the  parent class.

Comment: As I mentioned above I can run the tests as Junit tests individually or as a complete set. But I need to know if there is a way we can create a Test Suite where we can define what to run (including the order of tests)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is sequential execution of methods within a spec, have a look at `@spock.lang.Stepwise`, which is handy for testing workflows. Otherwise, you have the same possibilities as with plain JUnit: you can use JUnit (4) test suites, model test suites in your build tool of choice (which might not help within STS), or define test suites via Eclipse run configurations. I don't know how far support for the latter goes, but at the very least, it should allow you to run all tests in a package.

Answer (score 0):

If the tests you want to run in a specific order are part of the same spock Specification, then you can use the @Stepwise annotation to direct that the tests (feature methods) are executed in the order they appear in the Specification class.

As others mentioned, its best to avoid this dependency if you can because of the complexity it introduces. For example, what happens if the first test fails? Does that leave the system in a undefined state for the subsequent tests? So it would be better to prevent the intra-test dependencies with setup() and cleanup() methods (or setupSpec() and cleanupSpec()).

Another option is to combine two dependent tests into a single multi-stage test with multiple when:/then: block pairs in sequence.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. I'm happy with your second option (combining dependent tests into one) however the issue is they are functional tests. And if I have one big test then the test would take a long time to run. The reason being the latter part of the script has to wait until it receives an order before proceeding. In this case I would have to introduce an implicit wait in my script to be able to complete the e2e journey.